# pagination searching results

Tags: php, pagination

I am designing a real estate website and i have a search box in my first page which lets my users to decide what exactly they want, e.g they can narrow down their options for renting or buying or other stuffs. My code works perfectly fine and my pagination works to the point of breaking up the pages evenly, and calculating how many pages there need to be, and the first page of the pagination displays without error. But my problem begins when I click next or click on page X. When I select another page other than page 1 I get no results displayed.I think php can not remember posted forms. here is my code:

config.php

```
<?php
$db_host="localhost";
$db_user="root";
$db_pass="";
$db_name="realstate";
$db_table="agahi";
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "realstate");
mysqli_query($connect,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($connect,"SET character_set_connection='utf8'");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    die("unable to connect".mysqli_connect_errno());
}
$setting = array(
'paged_item' => 2
);
?>
```

search.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP HTML TABLE DATA SEARCH</title>
 <style>
@charset "uft-8";
@import url('reset.css');
body {

font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
background-color: #e2edff;
line-height: 125%;
padding: 15px;
font-size=13px;

}
</style>        
<link rel="stylesheet" href="paged_style.css">
</head>
<body>

            <form action="" method="post">    
<select name="valueToSearch1" style="width: 136px;">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>choose</option>
    <option name="" value="buy">buy</option>
    <option name="" value="rent">rent</option>
</select>
<div dir="rtl" style="margin-top:10px; style="text-align: right"  >     
    <input type='submit' name='search' value='Search' ></br></br></br>
</div>
            </form>
<?php
include("config.php");
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $valueToSearch1 = $_POST['valueToSearch1'];


@$page = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);


if(empty($page)){

    $page = 1;
}
$start = ($page - 1) * $setting['paged_item'];

$quer = "SELECT*FROM ".$db_table." WHERE 
 `case` LIKE '%".$valueToSearch1."%' ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT $start, ".$setting['paged_item']."";
 $query=mysqli_query($connect,$quer)
or die(mysqli_error());
//pagination
$total = "SELECT*FROM ".$db_table." WHERE 
`case` LIKE '%".$valueToSearch1."%'";
$totalll = mysqli_query($connect,$total)
or die(mysqli_error());
$count = mysqli_num_rows($totalll);
echo $count;
if($count - $setting['paged_item'] > 0){
    $paged_total = ceil($count / $setting['paged_item']);
    echo $paged_total;
    $paged_last = $paged_total;
    echo $paged_last;
    $paged_middle = $page + 4;
    $paged_start = $paged_middle - 4;

    if($page > 1){

        $paged_result = '<div class="paged-link"><a href="search.php?page=1" title="first page"</a></div>'."\n";                            
    }
    else{
        $paged_result = '<div class="paged-link-off">first</div>'."\n";                                 
    }

    if($page > 1){
        $paged_perv = $page - 1;
        $paged_result .= '<div class="paged-link"><a href="searchch.php?page='.$paged_perv.'" title="provious page"</a></div>'."\n";
    }
    else{
        $paged_result .= '<div class="paged-link-off">previous</div>'."\n";
    }

    for ($i=$paged_start-2; $i<=$paged_middle; $i++){
        if ($i > 0 && $i <= $paged_last){

            if($i == $page){
                $paged_result .= '<div class="paged-link-selected"><a href="search.php?page='.$i.'" title="page '.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></div>'."\n";
            }

            else{
                $paged_result .= '<div class="paged-link"><a href="search.php?page='.$i.'" title="page '.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></div>'."\n";
            }
        }
    }

    if($page <= $paged_last - 1){
        $paged_next = $page + 1;
        $paged_result .= '<div class="paged-link"><a href="search.php?page='.$paged_next.'" title="next page"</a></div>'."\n";
    }
    else{
        $paged_result .= '<div class="paged-link-off">Next</div>'."\n";
    }

    if($page <= $paged_last - 1){
        $paged_result .= '<div class="paged-link"><a href="search.php?page='.$paged_last.'" title="final page"</a></div>'."\n";
    }
    else{
        $paged_result .= '<div class="paged-link-off">final</div>'."\n";
    }
    $paged_result .= '<div class="paged-link-info">&raquo; page: '.$page.' out of '.$paged_total.'</div>'."\n";

    echo $paged_result; 
}   
}
?>
<table >


      <!-- populate table from mysql database -->
                <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)):?>
                <tr>

                            <th> <?php echo $row['case'];?> 

                </tr>
                <?php endwhile;?>
            </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use `$_POST` for pagination. Use `$_GET`. That way pages can be directly accessed via the address bar without having to physically click a button.

Comment: thank you.
I changed $_POST to $_GET. but still when I click next or click on page X. or select another page other than page 1 I get no results displayed. can you help me a little more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to send the searched text to the next page. You can add the parameter to the link as follows :

```
$paged_result .= '<div class="paged-link"><a href="search.php?page='.$paged_last.'&valueToSearch1='.$valueToSearch1.'" title="final page"</a></div>'."\n";
```

Add this to every link of pages you have : `&valueToSearch1='.$valueToSearch1`

Comment: thank you very much i edit my code but still I get no results from another pages other than page 1 . here is my new code

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP HTML TABLE DATA SEARCH</title>
 <style>
@charset "uft-8";
@import url('reset.css');
body {
 
font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
background-color: #e2edff;
line-height: 125%;
padding: 15px;
font-size=13px;

}

</style>
  
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="paged_style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
 <form action="" method="GET">    
 <select name="valueToSearch1" style="width: 136px;">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>choose</option>
    <option name="" value="buy">buy</option>
    <option name="" value="rent">rent</option>
</select>
<div dir="rtl" style="margin-top:10px; style="text-align: right"  >  
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="search"  ><br><br>
            </div>
   </form>
   
<?php
 error_reporting(0);

include("config.php");
if(isset($_GET['search']))
{
    $valueToSearch1 = $_GET['valueToSearch1'];


@$page = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);


if(empty($page)){
 
 $page = 1;
}
$start = ($page - 1) * $setting['paged_item'];


$quer = "SELECT*FROM ".$db_table." WHERE 
 `case` LIKE '%".$valueToSearch1."%' ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT $start, ".$setting['paged_item']."";

 $query=mysqli_query($connect,$quer)
or die(mysqli_error());

$total = "SELECT*FROM ".$db_table." WHERE 
`case` LIKE '%".$valueToSearch1."%'";
$totalll = mysqli_query($connect,$total)
or die(mysqli_error());

$count = mysqli_num_rows($totalll);
echo $count;

if($count - $setting['paged_item'] > 0){
 
 $paged_total = ceil($count / $setting['paged_item']);
 echo $paged_total;
 
 $paged_last = $paged_total;
 echo $paged_last;

 $paged_middle = $page + 4;

 $paged_start = $paged_middle - 4;
 
 
 if($page > 1){
  $paged_result = '<div class="paged-link"><a href="search.php?page=1 &valueToSearch1='.$valueToSearch1.'" title="fiest page"</a></div>'."\n";       
 }
 else{
  $paged_result = '<div class="paged-link-off">first</div>'."\n";         
 }
 
 if($page > 1){
  $paged_perv = $page - 1;
  $paged_result .= '<div class="paged-link"><a href="search.php?page='.$paged_perv.'&valueToSearch1='.$valueToSearch1.'" title="previous page"</a></div>'."\n";
 }
 else{
  $paged_result .= '<div class="paged-link-off">pre</div>'."\n";
 }
 
 for ($i=$paged_start-2; $i<=$paged_middle; $i++){
  if ($i > 0 && $i <= $paged_last){
   
   if($i == $page){
    $paged_result .= '<div class="paged-link-selected"><a href="search.php?page='.$i.'&valueToSearch1='.$valueToSearch1.'" title="page '.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></div>'."\n";
   }
   else{
    $paged_result .= '<div class="paged-link"><a href="search.php?page='.$i.'&valueToSearch1='.$valueToSearch1.'" title="page '.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></div>'."\n";
   }
  }
 }
 
 
 if($page <= $paged_last - 1){
  $paged_next = $page + 1;
  $paged_result .= '<div class="paged-link"><a href="search.php?page='.$paged_next.'&valueToSearch1='.$valueToSearch1.'" title="next page"</a></div>'."\n";
 }
 else{
  $paged_result .= '<div class="paged-link-off">next</div>'."\n";
 }
 
 
 if($page <= $paged_last - 1){
  $paged_result .= '<div class="paged-link"><a href="search.php?page='.$paged_last.'&valueToSearch1='.$valueToSearch1.'" title="last page"</a></div>'."\n";
 }
 else{
  $paged_result .= '<div class="paged-link-off">final</div>'."\n";
 }
 $paged_result .= '<div class="paged-link-info">&raquo; page: '.$page.' out of'.$paged_total.'</div>'."\n";

 echo $paged_result; 
} 

}
?>

        
  
            <table >
                

      <!-- populate table from mysql database -->
                <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)):?>
                <tr>

           <th> <?php echo $row['case'];?> </th>
                      
                </tr>
                <?php endwhile;?>
            </table>

</div>
<?php
$close = mysqli_close($connect);
?>
    </body>
</html>
```